# ORA-01008 error-Inserting a record into Oracle DB using OleDb

Tags: c#, oracle, visual-studio-2010

The code involves inserting a record from the values inputted in VS 2010 into Oracle DB using C# .The database has been created in sqlplus and upon debugging in VS ive encountered the error-ORA 01008. Th syntax matches with that of the default one. Can someone point out the error.

```
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection();
con.ConnectionString = "Provider="provider";Data Source=xxxx;User ID=usernamePassword=password";

con.Open();

string insertquery = "insert into CHECKLIST(ID,CUSTOMER,SERVER,CHECK_TYPE,DESCRIPTION,PATH_URL,TEXT,CAT3,CAT4) Values (:id,:customer,:server,:check1,:description,:path1,:text1,:cat3,:cat4)";

OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(insertquery, con);
OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(insertquery, con);

cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter(":id", TextBox9.Text));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter(":customer", TextBox1.Text));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter(":server", TextBox2.Text));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter(":check1", TextBox3.Text));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter(":description", TextBox4.Text));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter(":path1", TextBox5.Text));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter(":text1", TextBox6.Text));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter(":cat3", TextBox7.Text));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter(":cat4", TextBox8.Text));

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

Response.Write("Registration is successful");

con.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

From [`OleDbCommand.Parameters` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> The OLE DB .NET Provider does not support named parameters for passing
>   parameters to an SQL statement or a stored procedure called by an
>   OleDbCommand when CommandType is set to Text. In this case, the
>   question mark (?) placeholder must be used. For example:
>
> SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE CustomerID = ?
>
> Therefore, the order in which OleDbParameter objects are added to the
>   OleDbParameterCollection must directly correspond to the position of
>   the question mark placeholder for the parameter in the command text.

Try with `?` to specify your parameters.

```
string insertquery = @"insert into CHECKLIST(ID,CUSTOMER,SERVER,CHECK_TYPE,DESCRIPTION,PATH_URL,TEXT,CAT3,CAT4)
                     Values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
```

Your `OleDbDataAdapter` seems pointless as well. You just inserting a data. You don't return any data to keep in `OleDbDataAdapter`.

Also use [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your `OleDbConnection` and `OleDbCommand` like;

```
using(OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(conString))
using(OleDbCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
{
    // Set your CommandText property.
    // Define and add your parameter values.
    // Open your OleDbConnection.
    // Execute your query with ExecuteNonQuery.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.That error got resolved though.however on debugging encountered the error saying: MSDAORA' failed with no error message available, result code: E_FAIL(0x80004005) type of error..how to rectify this error

Comment: @KaashyapSarma You are quite welcome. I can't think anything about your second problem with such a less information. If you have an another question, you should ask it as a separate question as well.